# What exactly does cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() do in my program

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

```
string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\it101\\LoginForm\\App_Data\\registration.mdb";

string query = "INSERT INTO [registration] ([UserID] , [Name] , [Contact_no] , [City]) values (123, 'abc' ,12345, 'pqr')";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And what if i do not write cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() at the end of my program? 
And if the query needs to be executed why is it written executeNonquery() instead of executeQuery()?

Comment: Think of this as preparing a meal - those are all the lines before `ExecuteNonQuery()`, then actually eating it. Without the `ExecuteNonQuery()` you'll be just wasting the meal. :)

Comment: _And what if i do not write cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() at the end of my program?_ Try and see `:)`. _ And if the query needs to be executed why is it written executeNonquery() instead of executeQuery()?_ Ask to Microsoft .NET Team `:)` You can't figure out what this method do with using Google in a few minutes by the way..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Thankx a tone. That's an excellent way to explain. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

if we want to deal with database two things will happen i.e; Modifying,Retrieving

**Modifying:**

In Modifying Section,we have *Insert*, *Delete* ,*Update*,...queries.so for this we need to use ExecuteNonQuery command.why because we are not querying a database, we are modifying.

*syntax:*

*cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Method*

**Retrieving:**

In this we query a database by using *Select* Statement.For this we use ExecuteReader(),ExecuteScalar()

If select Query return more than one record.we need to use ExecuteReader()

If select Query return only one record.we need to use ExecuteScalar()

*syntax:*

*cmd.ExecuteReader() Method*

*cmd.ExecuteScalar() Method*

The above statements(ExecuteReader(),ExecuteScalar(),SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()) are used to execute command statement which you give in SqlCommand.If you dont use, your command not be executed.

Comment: Thank you. That was quite understanding and detailed. Things got more clear! :)

Comment: To nitpick: `ExecuteScalar()` returns the [first column of the first row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8), so you can't use it to return an entire record.

Answer (score 8):

ExecuteNonQuery executes a query that is not expected to produce any results (e.g. an UPDATE, or INSERT).

ExecuteQuery executes a query that is supposed to produce a result (i.e. a SELECT).

If you do not write ExecuteNonQuery at the end, your query won't be executed.

Answer (score 5):

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Executes statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.
For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.

[executeQuery Method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378540.aspx)

Runs the given SQL statement and returns a single SQLServerResultSet object.

If you want to execute your query you should use ExecuteNonQuery