# What is non query in DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, sql, database, api

What is non query in `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`?

I am confused by the naming of the method. If it would be named `ExecuteQuery` instead of the `ExecuteNonQuery`, then I would have no questions. But otherwise I do not understand why is it called `ExecuteNonQuery`, while it description from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Common_DbCommand_ExecuteNonQuery) clearly states that the method does execute a query:

> When overridden in a derived class, executes a SQL statement against a connection object.

Comment: You won't get the rows you might expect when executing a Select-Statement with `ExecuteNonQuery`. It returns just the amount of affected rows. So it is just useful to modify, not to retrieve data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() do in my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143203/what-exactly-does-cmd-executenonquery-do-in-my-program)

Comment: Would you be content if it was named `ExecuteQueryButDoNotReturnAResultSet`

Comment: Well, _query_ means _answer this question_. An INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE statement are not questions, they are _orders_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery doesn't return any rows.

SO, you can use ExecuteNonQuery method like this situation.

1. You want to insert a row

   - insert does not return result row
2. You want to Update a field

   - also update too
3. you want to Delete a row or table or database

   - also delete too

I'm sorry for not helpful your question

Answer (score 0):

Use ExecuteNonQuery for Insert, Update or Delete and also for Procedures, DDL staments