# Parameter 'p_room_types' not found in the collection

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

I am new to .NET and was trying to work with MySQL and .NET Core.
Below is my stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertRoomNecessities`(

  IN p_room_types longtext,

  IN p_rent_types longtext,

  IN p_meal_types longtext,

  IN p_cooling_types longtext,

  IN p_bed_types longtext

  )
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_room longtext DEFAULT Concat(p_room_types , ',');

    DECLARE v_rent longtext DEFAULT Concat(p_rent_types , ',');

    DECLARE v_bed longtext DEFAULT Concat(p_bed_types , ',');

    DECLARE v_cooling longtext DEFAULT Concat(p_cooling_types , ',');

    DECLARE v_meal longtext DEFAULT Concat(p_meal_types , ',');

    DECLARE v_pos INT;

    DECLARE v_len INT;

    DECLARE v_rentpos INT;

    DECLARE v_rentlen INT;

    DECLARE v_bedPos INT;

    DECLARE v_bedLen INT;

    DECLARE v_coolingPos INT;

    DECLARE v_coolingLen INT;

    DECLARE v_mealPos INT;

    DECLARE v_mealLen INT;

    DECLARE v_value varchar(100);

    DECLARE v_rentValue varchar(100);

    DECLARE v_bedValue varchar(100);

    DECLARE v_coolingValue varchar(100);

    DECLARE v_mealValue varchar(100);



    -- Room type

    IF (v_room IS NOT NULL) OR (CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(v_room)) > 0) THEN

        set v_pos = 0;

    END IF;

        set v_len = 0;

        WHILE LOCATE(',', v_room, v_pos+1)>0

        DO

            set v_len = LOCATE(',', v_room, v_pos+1) - v_pos;

            set v_value = SUBSTRING(v_room, v_pos, v_len);

            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RoomType WHERE RoomType.Room_Type = v_value)

            THEN

            --  SQLINES DEMO *** f not exists

                INSERT INTO RoomType (Room_Type)

                VALUES (v_value);

            END IF;

            set v_pos = LOCATE(',', v_room, v_pos+v_len) +1;

        END WHILE;



    -- Rent type

    IF (v_rent IS NOT NULL) OR (CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(v_rent)) > 0) THEN

        set v_rentpos = 0;

    END IF;

        set v_rentlen = 0;

        WHILE LOCATE(',', v_rent, v_rentpos+1)>0

        DO

            set v_rentlen = LOCATE(',', v_rent, v_rentpos+1) - v_rentpos;

            set v_rentValue = SUBSTRING(v_rent, v_rentpos, v_rentlen);

            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RoomRent WHERE RoomRent.Room_Rent = v_rentValue)

            THEN

            --  SQLINES DEMO *** f not exists

                INSERT INTO RoomRent (Room_Rent)

                VALUES (v_rentValue);

            END IF;

            set v_rentpos = LOCATE(',', v_rent, v_rentpos+v_rentlen) +1;

        END WHILE;



    -- Bed type

    IF (v_bed IS NOT NULL) OR (CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(v_bed)) > 0) THEN

        set v_bedPos = 0;

    END IF;

        set v_bedLen = 0;

        WHILE LOCATE(',', v_bed, v_bedPos+1)>0

        DO

            set v_bedLen = LOCATE(',', v_bed, v_bedPos+1) - v_bedPos;

            set v_bedValue = SUBSTRING(v_bed, v_bedPos, v_bedLen);

            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RoomBedType WHERE RoomBedType.BedType = v_bedValue)

            THEN

            --  SQLINES DEMO *** f not exists

                INSERT INTO RoomBedType (BedType)

                VALUES (v_bedValue);

            END IF;

            set v_bedPos = LOCATE(',', v_bed, v_bedPos+v_bedLen) +1;

        END WHILE;



    IF (v_cooling IS NOT NULL) OR (CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(v_cooling)) > 0) THEN

            set v_coolingPos = 0;

    END IF;

            set v_coolingLen = 0;

            WHILE LOCATE(',', v_cooling, v_coolingPos+1)>0

            DO

                set v_coolingLen = LOCATE(',', v_cooling, v_coolingPos+1) - v_coolingPos;

                set v_coolingValue = SUBSTRING(v_cooling, v_coolingPos, v_coolingLen);

                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM RoomCoolingType WHERE RoomCoolingType.CoolingType = v_coolingValue)

                THEN

                --  SQLINES DEMO *** f not exists

                    INSERT INTO RoomCoolingType (CoolingType)

                    VALUES (v_coolingValue);

                END IF;

                set v_coolingPos = LOCATE(',', v_cooling, v_coolingPos+v_coolingLen) +1;

            END WHILE;



    IF (v_meal IS NOT NULL) OR (CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(v_meal)) > 0) THEN

            set v_mealPos = 0;

    END IF;

            set v_mealLen = 0;

            WHILE LOCATE(',', v_meal, v_mealPos+1)>0

            DO

                set v_mealLen = LOCATE(',', v_meal, v_mealPos+1) - v_mealPos;

                set v_mealValue = SUBSTRING(v_meal, v_mealPos, v_mealLen);

                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MealType WHERE MealType.Meal_Type = v_mealValue)

                THEN

                --  SQLINES DEMO *** f not exists

                    INSERT INTO MealType (Meal_Type)

                    VALUES (v_mealValue);

                END IF;

                set v_mealPos = LOCATE(',', v_meal, v_mealPos+v_mealLen) +1;

            END WHILE;

END
```

My c# .netCore's code.

```
[HttpPost("InsertRoomEssential")]
        public async Task<object> InsertRoomEssential(RoomEssentials newModelInfo)
        {
            try {
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Server=Localhost;Database=HotelManagement;Uid=root;Pwd=Onkar@123;");
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("InsertRoomNecessities", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_room_types", newModelInfo.Room_types);
                cmd.Parameters["@p_room_types"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_rent_types", newModelInfo.Rent_type);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_meal_types", newModelInfo.Meal_types);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cooling_types", newModelInfo.Cooling_types);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_bed_types", newModelInfo.Bed_types);
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader i = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                con.Close();

                //if (i != 0)
                //{
                //    return await Task.FromResult(new ResponseModel(ResponseCode.OK, "Update is done", null));
                //}
                return await Task.FromResult(new ResponseModel(ResponseCode.Error, "", "Faild to add data"));
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(new ResponseModel(ResponseCode.Error, ex.Message, null));
            }
        }
```

Error happens to be on this line below.

```
MySqlDataReader i = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Can I know what exactly is being going wrong in here?
I did try the other solutions from similar questions on StackOverflow. But I couldn't make my code work.

Comment: Instead of `MySqlDataReader i = cmd.ExecuteReader();` I think you just want `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Please add the full exception message and callstack to your question. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: @Charlieface after using cmd.ExecureNonQuery() I get this as my error "cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'MySQL.Data.MySQLClient.MySQLDataReader'

Comment: Sorry why are you trying to save it as a DataReader, it will just return the rowcount as an integer, which you can ignore. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143203/what-exactly-does-cmd-executenonquery-do-in-my-program